# What is the flow of K-Means++ , I would like to know exactly differences between K-Mean and K-Means++?

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I would like to know the differences between K-Mean and K-Means++ algorithm .If anyone understand the flow of K-Means++ algorithm, could you explain me with example please?Although , I understand K-Mean algorithm,finding how to implement K-Means++ algorithm is difficult for me because I don't understand the work flow of this algo:  clearly.
Thanks Everyone.

Comment: [Here is a very clear explanation that I've used to implement Kmeans in Java.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/k-means-1.html) Your question however has no relation to Java as it stands.

Comment: Thanks. But I do want to know K-Means++ algorithm not K-Means.They are different.

Comment: All sorts of documents: http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/vldb12-kmpar.pdf

Comment: could you explain me K-Means++ algorithm with example.How it works and How calculate centroid?I think you could help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that you want to know the difference between **k-means** and **k-means++** is not accurate. Because, those two algorithms are not comparable, but rather, they integrate with each other.

[Kmeans++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means++) definition from wikipedia:

> k-means++ is an algorithm for choosing the initial values (or "seeds") for the k-means clustering algorithm

and the existence of such an algorithm is needed for the fact that, k-means has problems with performance and accuracy (depends on the way you analyze your data and your whole pre-processing step).

as for your question about:

> finding how to implement K-Means++ algorithm is difficult for me because I don't understand the work flow of this algo: clearly.

You start with a random point in your data-set, then compute the distance between each point in the set and the chosen point (Euclidean distance can be one of your choices). Then, Choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a [weighted probability distribution](http://www.ehow.com/how_5959518_calculate-weighted-probabilities.html) where a point x is chosen with [probability proportional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29) to D(x)2. and redo the same thing (other than starting with the random point) till you reach the `k` clusters you needed (`k` should be passed to the algorithm as a parameter).

after that you have the `k` clusters, you can continue with `k-means`. 
**Note** that this is mostly from wikipedia, but my point here is that you are taking k-means++ as an alternative to k-means, which is not, it is what the aforementioned definition stated.

Lastly, k-means++ is good enough to help overcome some problems which k-means has, but by passing the number of clusters (`k`) as an input param to it, it is no longer scalable. However, there is another version of k-means called [k-means2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661142/whats-the-difference-between-kmeans-and-kmeans2-in-scipy)(I didn't search for other sources) that might overcome the scalablility issues if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you , I'll try to know that deeply .